# Is it possible to reserialize all via an URL call

Tags: helix, unicorn

I have a helix project configured to use unicorn. on our production environment the marketing team have been adding content for around 2 months so there are thousands of changes to the master database.

I've restored a DB locally and reserilaized each project so we can check in the new yaml files to source control. But in our Helix solution there over 60 projects and I've had to middle click the reserialize button on each project listed in unicorn.

Is there a query string like `?verb=sync` but to reserilaize all projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup - and its just as simple as syncing all. Just change the verb to `Reserialize` like this:

```
http://mysite/unicorn.aspx?verb=Reserialize
```

and it will reserialize all the configurations in the same way that `verb=sync`, syncs them all.

A second option would be to tick the box next to the `Configurations` header and then `Reserialize Selected` button. But this checkbox may not appear if you have no serialized items on your file store.

[image]